# c# EnumerateFiles wildcard returning non matches?

Tags: c#, .net

As a simplified example I am executing the following

```
IEnumerable<string> files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, @"2010*.xml", 
    SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).ToList();
```

In my results set I am getting a few files which do no match the file pattern.  According to msdn searchPattern wildcard is "Zero or more characters" and not a reg ex.  An example is that I am getting a file name back as "2004_someothername.xml".

For information there are in excess of 25,000 files in the folder.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

Comment: Can you post some examples of filenames that are matching that should not?

Comment: You say "as a simplified example" - have you tested that the code you show will actually return the file you claim? It's more likely that the issue is caused in the non-simplified example...!

Comment: Example you provided works fine. Just tested it . So if you can please post actual code that isn't working properly

Comment: @Michael Goldshteyn: Now why don't you just post that as an answer? :)

Comment: @Steven, you're right and I just did...

Comment: @Sam - Random thought, but how many characters are in the path-string?

Comment: @All, I updated my answer with the reason for this behavior.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is due to how Windows does wildcard matching - **it includes the encoded 8.3 filenames in its wildcard search**, resulting in some surprising matches!

A way to get around this bug is to retest all file results that come back through the OS wildcard match and test with a manual comparison of the wildcard to each (long) file name. Another way is to [turn off 8.3 filenames altogether via the registry](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/121007). I have been burned by this on numerous occasions, including having important (non-matching) files get deleted via a wildcard based del command from the command prompt.

To summarize, be *very careful*, especially if you have many files in a directory on making any critical production decisions or taking any actions based on an OS file/wildcard match, without a secondary verification of results.

Here is an [explanation](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/win32-cli-search-wildcard-matching.html) of this bizarre behavior.

Another explanation from [O'Reilly's site](http://oreilly.com/pub/h/3230).

Comment: Care to link to the bug report?

Comment: Do you have a reference on that bug? I'm unable to recreate it in Powershell, with 50,000 files, using the system.IO.Directory class.

Comment: @All, after doing further research on the cause of this, I updated my answer with the explanation for the problem and references.

Comment: thank you, great answer.  At least I know I'm not just being plain stupid. I can happily code around this.

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce your problem with the follow code (Sorry, VB). It creates 55,000 zero-byte files named `2000_0001.xml` through `2010_5000.xml`. Then it looks for all of the files that start with 2010. On my machine (Windows 7 SP1 32-bit) it returns 5,174 files instead of just 5,000.

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On

Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Private TempFolder As String = Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop, "Temp")

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        CreateFiles()

        Dim Files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(TempFolder, "2010*.xml", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).ToList()
        Using FS As New FileStream(Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop, "Report.txt"), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read)
            Using SW As New StreamWriter(FS, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII)
                For Each F In Files
                    SW.WriteLine(F)
                Next
            End Using
        End Using


        DeleteFiles()
    End Sub

    Private Sub CreateFiles()
        If Not Directory.Exists(TempFolder) Then Directory.CreateDirectory(TempFolder)
        Dim Bytes() As Byte = {}
        Dim Name As String
        For Y = 2000 To 2010
            Trace.WriteLine(Y)
            For I = 1 To 5000
                Name = String.Format("{0}_{1}.xml", Y, I.ToString.PadLeft(4, "0"c))
                File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(TempFolder, Name), Bytes)
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
    Private Sub DeleteFiles()
        Directory.Delete(TempFolder, True)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Even though it's VB, +1 for the big effort! :)

Comment: I figure since all the C# guys respond to VB questions with C# I'd do the opposite! Actually, that's just what I had open at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution for the MS bug (which possibly uses Windows File Search underneath, which would be terrible for your results...), but a solution as a workaround, which gives you some extra leverage and control over the results:

```
var files = from file in 
      Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*",
      SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
      where (new FileInfo(file)).Name.StartsWith("2010") &&
          (new FileInfo(file)).Extension == "xml"
      select dir;
```

Answer (score 1):

I just tried your example and I can't see it doing anything wrong, so I guess there's more to your environment and/or the "non simplified" code that isn't covered here.

I've used this code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Starting...");
IEnumerable<string> files = Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\\temp\\test\\2010", @"2010*.xml", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).ToList();

foreach (string file in files)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Found[{0}]", file);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

In my folder structure i've created the following:

c:\temp\test\2010\2004_something.xml
c:\temp\test\2010\2010_abc.xml
c:\temp\test\2010\2010_def.xml

The output of the application is simply:

```
Starting...
Found[C:\temp\test\2010\2010_abc.xml]
Found[C:\temp\test\2010\2010_def.xml]
```

Can you provide some more feedback as to what is happening in your scenario, in the real app? or can you reproduce the problem in a smaller app?

Answer (score 0):

Having suffered the same problem, and finding this post I thought I would post my solution:

```
IEnumerable<string> Files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(e.FileName, "*.xml").Where(File => File.EndsWith(".xml", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

This only tests the suffix but eliminates matches to my backup files that end .xml~.